# diffraction and polarization

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light, polarization, diffraction

When the light passes through a polarizer, it passes through an aperture/slit, shouldn't the polarized portion of the light diffract after it passes through the polarizer's aperture/slit?

Comment: Who says it doesn't?

Comment: The way I study it in high school is that the light wave when polarized the electric field is kept to propagate as a wave in single direction. @EmilioPisanty

Comment: If the photons are diffracted it could  make most photon entangled and EPR experiments useless. After the photons are filtered at polarizers they need to maintain a direct trajectories to the detectors. Or at least the same trajectories so they can be considered correlated or not.

Comment: @BillAlsept That's a bunch of hogwash, with no bearing to the question as posed.

Comment: Then tell me how you can account for correlation if you can't even account for trajectory

Answer (score 0):

You should find something about Jones vector and Poincare sphere first. This could help

Comment: How would that help?